# Crear un pedigrí

Tags: r, tidyverse

De pronto saben como crear una función en R que permita crear un pedigrí con distintas generaciones (F1, F2, etc) a partir de una generación 0 (F0). Por ejemplo, tengo una generación inicial con un total de 451 individuos (plantas en realidad):

| ID |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| .. |
| 451 |

En la primera generación quisiera obtener una descendencia del cruce de esos 451 individuos del forma aleatoria con un tamaño cualquiera (que yo pueda indicar también). Por ejemplo, los individuos 1 y 2 formarian al individuo 49 (1x2 -> 452), los individuos 2 y 4 formarian al individuo 50 (2x4 -> 453), etc. Luego en la segunda generación el cruce sería distinto ya que permitiría la autopolinización entre los individuos de la primera generación. Por ejemplo, el individuo 452 formaría al individuo 851 (452x452 -> 851). Aquí también debería indicar el número de individuos que quisiera obtener. Luego de estos cruces se crearia una conjunto de datos donde se especifique la id del individuo, la id del padre, la id de la madre y a que generación pertenece, así:

| ind | padre | madre | generación |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

Por ejemplo tengo este código, que haría paso a paso lo que quiero lograr en la primera generación:

```
Pob_fun <- tibble(
  id = 1:451
  ) # Aquí genero los individuos que harían parte de la generación 0.
```

```
F1_a <- Pob_fun %>%
  sample_n(2) %>%
  mutate(Relacion = c('Padre', 'Madre')) %>%
  pivot_wider(
    names_from = Relacion,
    values_from = id
    ) %>%
  mutate(id = 452) # Creo el primer individuo de la primera generación (F1).
```

```
F1_b <- Pob_fun %>%
  sample_n(2) %>%
  mutate(Relacion = c('Padre', 'Madre')) %>%
  pivot_wider(
    names_from = Relacion,
    values_from = id
  ) %>%
  mutate(id = 453) # Creo el segundo individuo de la primera generación (F1).
```

```
F1 <- bind_rows(F1_a, F1_b) %>%
  mutate(Generacion = 1) # Uno los dos anteriores y creo una nueva columna llamada generación.
```

Sin embargo esto no es eficiente ya que sería uno por uno, y si yo quisiera 400 individuos de la primera generación tendría que repetir este proceso 398 veces más.

La segunda generación la cree así (que tampoco creo que es eficiente):

```
F2_a <- F1 %>%
  select(id) %>%
  rename(Prog1 = id) %>%
  sample_n(1) %>%
  mutate(Prog2 = Prog1) %>%
  mutate(id = 456)

F2_b <- F2_a %>%
  mutate(
    id = recode(
      .x = id,
      `456` = 457L
      )
    ) # Aquí, el primer individuo seleccionado al azar de la primera generación es padre y madre de los individuos 456 y 457 de la segunda generación.
```

```
F2_c <- F1 %>%
  select(id) %>%
  rename(Prog1 = id) %>%
  sample_n(1) %>%
  mutate(Prog2 = Prog1) %>%
  mutate(id = 458)

F2_d <- F2_c %>%
  mutate(
    id = recode(
      .x = id,
      `458` = 459L
    )
  ) # Aquí, el segundo individuo seleccionado al azar de la primera generación es padre y madre de los individuos 458 y 459 de la segunda generación.
```

```
F2 <- bind_rows(F2_a, F2_b, F2_c, F2_d) %>%
  mutate(Generacion = 2) # Uno los dos anteriores y creo una nueva columna llamada generación.
```

Les agradecería cualquier ayuda que me puedan brindar.

Comment: Si no demuestras que eres parte del esfuerzo por resolver tu propia duda (por ejemplo agregando un [ejemplo minimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) a la pregunta) esta terminará cerrada y posiblemente no recibas respuestas.

Comment: @DanteS. entendido. Ojala lo que añadí se pueda entender. Mucha gracias.